# Prevent Ghostscript from writing errors to standard output

Tags: stdout, stderr, ghostscript

I'm using Ghostscript to rasterize the first page of a PDF file to JPEG. To avoid creating tempfiles, the PDF data is piped into Ghoscripts's stdin and the JPEG is "drained" on stdout. This pipeline works like a charm until GS receives invalid PDF data: Instead of reporting all error messages on stderr as I would have expected, it still writes some of the messages to *stdout* instead.

To reproduce:

```
$ echo "Not a PDF" >test.txt
$ /usr/bin/gs -q -sDEVICE=jpeg -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 \
    -r300 -sOutputFile=- - < test.txt 2>/dev/null
Error: /undefined in Not
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
...
```

Note the `2>/dev/null` above does not suppress the error messages. Ghostscript's documentation already warned that writing to stdout requires the `-q` flag to suppress messages on stdout, but I still seem to be missing something here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to *really* silence Ghostscript, modify your command line like this:

```
/usr/bin/gs -q        \
     -sstdout=%stderr \
     -sDEVICE=jpeg    \
     -dBATCH          \
     -dNOPAUSE        \
     -dLastPage=1     \
     -r300            \
     -sOutputFile=-   \
     - < test.txt 2>/dev/null
```

The addition of `-sstdout=%stderr` allows Postscript stdout to be redirected, while still allowing drivers to write to stdout. (That patch is in Ghostscript since ~2001, Sept 22.)

Comment: Thanks, pipitas -- this is exactly what I was looking for. I had to explicitely specify `-sstdout=/dev/null`, however, since `%sstderr` would create a like-named file in the current directory.

For future reference, here is the original mailing list thread discussing the patch:
http://www.ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-code-review/2001-March/000273.html

Comment: There's a typo over there. It should be `%stderr` without the double s

Comment: how to silence ghostscript in windows ?

Comment: @user889030: Same command line, bug replace *`/usr/bin/gs`* by *`\path\to\gswin64c.exe`* and *`/dev/null`* by *`nul`*.